# How to implement the polylabel function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, geojson

I need to calculate the center (or rather the visible/inner centroid - this is a problem with U-shaped polygons) of a complex polygon, so i found this library called "polylabel" by mapbox on github.

Link: https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel

The problem is that there aren't any instructions on how to implement this on a local html file, where i stored my geojson object inside the javascript section.

I tried making a new js file, copying the code found on github inside of it and then importing it into the hmtl file but i get this error:

```
polylabel.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at polylabel.js:3:13
(anonymous) @ polylabel.js:3
polylabel.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Queue is not a constructor
at polylabel (polylabel.js:35:21)
at parceleTest.html:85:33
```

this leads me to believe that polylabel is a node.js function so it is supposed to run on the server side, but i'm still very new to this and very confused, can someone tell me how to call this function in my local javascript?

i also tried using this version:

```
<script src="https://bundle.run/@mapbox/polylabel@1.0.2"></script>
```

but it doesn't work or i'm missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: That library is for Node.js. You cannot use `require` in a browser.

Comment: unfortunately, yeah.. im going to install node.js but even then, how and from where do i call this function?

Comment: You'll need to use a tool such as https://browserify.org/

Btw: the successor of `require`, namely JavaScript modules `import` are natively supported by modern browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules